# How to find the groups of consecutives not NaN values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, filter

I am looking for a filter method that could find the groups of consecutives not NaN values in a list and return the indexes of the first and last elements of these groups.

For example the list

> [Nan, Nan, 4, 63, 34, Nan, Nan, Nan, 234, 3, Nan]

should return tuples for each group:

> [[2,4],[8,9]]

I made a function for pandas  dataframes that works but I would like to know if there is a simple method:

```
def find_groups_indexes(db):
    groups_indexes = []
    for i in  range(len(db)-1):
        if db.iloc[i].isnull().all()==True and db.iloc[i+1].isnull().all()==False:
            subgroup=[i+1]
        if db.iloc[i].isnull().all()==False and db.iloc[i+1].isnull().all()==True:
            subgroup.append(i)
            groups_indexes.append(subgroup)
            subgroup=[]
    print('\ngroups = ', groups_indexes)
    return groups_indexes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should be doing the job:

1. first finding the index where the data is not nan
2. then finding how many groups you have
3. finally getting the first and last value of the group
4. the if statement make sure only to add series of multiple no nan
   values.

short version

```py
data=np.argwhere(~np.isnan(values)).flatten()
[[array[0], array[-1]] for array in np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != 1)[0]+1) if array[0] != array[-1]]
```

long version:

```py
data=np.argwhere(~np.isnan(values)).flatten()
group_data = np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != 1)[0]+1)

solution = []
for array in group_data:
    if array[0] != array[-1]:
        indexes = [array[0], array[-1]]
        solution.append(indexes)
```